# error occurs when an Activity is unable to start due to an InflateException

Tags: android, java.lang.class

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.widget.Button

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace.  Whenever you see this, there will be a second exception immediately below it.  That's your real error

Comment: you have a error on your XML where you add any Button .Check it or show here